# Removing overlapping x-axis labels in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, label

I'm new to python and attempting to chart some time series data. I'm using pyplot to create 3 stacked line charts which have the same x-axis (dates), but a different scale for the y-axes. However, each y-axis, as well as the x-axis for the bottom chart, have overlapping labels. There are labels generated from 0 to 1, as well as axis labels from my data set. How do I turn 'off' the auto-generated 0 to 1 labels on the y-axes and the bottom x-axis?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1,sharex='all', squeeze=False, figsize=(12,8))

ax = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(df1['date'], df1['value'])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(df2['date'], df2['value'])

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(df3['date'], df3['value'])
plt.show()
```

You can see the issue in the below picture. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already created subplots with all the axes in the initial assignment

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1,sharex='all', squeeze=False, figsize=(12,8))
```

therefore the following assignements of

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)
```

are not only unnecessary, but they seem to overlap the already created subplots (if you change it to add_subplot(2,1,1) you will notice it just starts dividing figure again and overlaying axes on top of each other).

What you want to do, is access the axes created in plt.subplots() call:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1,sharex='all', squeeze=False, figsize=(12,8))

ax[0].plot(df1['date'], df1['value'])

ax[1].plot(df2['date'], df2['value'])

ax[2].plot(df3['date'], df3['value'])
plt.show()
```

**Simulated Output:**

Data from seaborn tips dataset

[image]